# Registering ObservableCollection as self and as IEnumerable<> in Autofac causes circular dependency exception

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, observablecollection

I would like to have the same collection sometimes be visible as `IEnumerable<T>` and sometimes as `ObservableCollection<T>` but I get an *Autofac* error:

> Circular component dependency detected

Here is my code:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ObservableCollection<Foo>>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
       .AsSelf()
       .As<IEnumerable<Foo>>();

using (var containter = builder.Build())
{
    var foos = containter.Resolve<ObservableCollection<Foo>>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Autofac* try to use a constructor of `ObservableCollection<T>` that takes a parameter of type `IEnumerable<T>` that's why you have a circular dependency exception.

To resolve this you can use the following code :

```
builder.Register(c => new ObservableCollection<IFoo>())
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
       .AsSelf()
       .As<IEnumerable<IFoo>>();
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<ObservableCollection<Foo>>()
       .FindConstructorsWith(t => new[] { t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) })
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
       .AsSelf()
       .As<IEnumerable<Foo>>();
```